# Catching the Access Token sent by Facebook after successful authentication

Tags: python, facebook

I am trying to make an app for authenticating user with their facebook account in python. App opens the facebook login page in web browser. After user logs in, facebook redirects it to thei dummy success page. At that moment i need to capture that redirect url in my app. I am not able to catch that URL.

I am opening fb login page by using webbrowser.open . How can i catch the redirect url after opening web browser?

Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Thanks,
Tara Singh

Comment: are you using the Facebook official Python library? It handles a lot of stuff for you.

Comment: No, I am not trying to do any real work, just authentication and then getting the token back to my application. But somehow i am not able to catch the token which is present in the redirect url.

Answer (score 0):

There's a getLoginUrl in the facebook SDK. You might want to look at that.

-Roozbeh

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Facebook Python lib https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/